# Flutter change color when button gets clicked

Tags: flutter, user-interface, setstate, expandable

I am working on an app where the user is able to expand and collapse text.
I want to text at the bottom to be blurred. As soon as the user expands the text the text should be displayed normal. When the text gets collapsed again, I want the text at the bottom again to be blurred.
I solved it the following way. My problem is that when the user collapse the text, the text at the bottom is not blurred again.

Here is my code:

```
class ExpandableText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  const ExpandableText({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpandableText> createState() => _ExpandableTextState();
}

class _ExpandableTextState extends State<ExpandableText> {
  late String firstHalf;
  late String secondHalf;

  bool hiddenText = true;

  Color fadeStrong = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8);
  Color fadeWeak = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6);

  // double textHeight = Dimensions.screenHight / 5.63;
  double textHeight = 180;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.text.length > textHeight) {
      firstHalf = widget.text.substring(0, textHeight.toInt());
      secondHalf =
          widget.text.substring(textHeight.toInt() + 1, widget.text.length);
    } else {
      firstHalf = widget.text;
      secondHalf = "";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Container(
        child: secondHalf.isEmpty
            ? Text(
                firstHalf,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )
            : Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    hiddenText ? ("$firstHalf...") : (firstHalf + secondHalf),
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        hiddenText = !hiddenText;
                        hiddenText
                            ? fadeStrong = fadeStrong
                            : fadeStrong = Colors.transparent;
                    hiddenText
                        ? fadeWeak = fadeWeak
                        : fadeWeak = Colors.transparent;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        hiddenText
                            ? const Text(
                                'Read more',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              )
                            : const Text('Read less',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                        Icon(
                          hiddenText
                              ? Icons.arrow_drop_down
                              : Icons.arrow_drop_up_outlined,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 52),
        height: 20,
        color: fadeStrong,
      ),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32),
        height: 20,
        color: fadeWeak,
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

[image: Text collapsed]

[image: Text expanded]

[image: Text collapsed again]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you overrides the color on tap event, that lose the initial reference

```
               onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    hiddenText = !hiddenText;
                    hiddenText
                        ? fadeStrong = fadeStrong
                        : fadeStrong = Colors.transparent;
                hiddenText
                    ? fadeWeak = fadeWeak
                    : fadeWeak = Colors.transparent;
                  });
                },
```

maybe you should try something like that will help you

```
               onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    hiddenText = !hiddenText;
                    hiddenText
                        ? fadeStrong = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8)
                        : fadeStrong = Colors.transparent;
                hiddenText
                    ? fadeWeak = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)
                    : fadeWeak = Colors.transparent;
                  });
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use ReadMore in flutter

For ex: ReadMoreText(
'Flutter is Google’s mobile UI open source framework to build high-quality native (super fast) interfaces for iOS and Android apps with the unified codebase.',
trimLines: 2,
preDataText: "AMANDA",
preDataTextStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
trimMode: TrimMode.Line,
trimCollapsedText: '...Show more',
trimExpandedText: ' show less',
),

Comment: Always please add code as a code snippet and not as text whenever you answer/ask so that.